# How can I move a ul list bullet marker very slightly to one direction?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a typora theme and styling it with CSS. I don't really have much access to the HTML generated since it's generated by the program, but it does provide a lot of flexibility.

I'm trying to just move UL ::markers a couple pixels to the right.

[image: Markers]

Anyone know a solution?

Thanks much.

Comment: `ul{ padding-inline-start: 42px}` - default is 40px (Chrome: Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: It would be more beneficial to show the code you have tried rather than asking other community members to code the solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @enhzflep suggested in a comment, you could increase the space before the bullet by applying `padding` on the `ul` in CSS. Here's how it's done (I have made two lists—ordered and unordered):

```css
ul {
padding-inline-start: 39px
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li> First </li>
<li> Second </li>
<li> Third </li>
</ol>

<hr>

<ul> 
<li> First </li>
<li> Second </li>
<li> Third </li>
</ul>
```