# how to make the li element do not displace under the ul or ol element

Tags: html

By default when we put li

```html
  <ul>
       <li>smooth</li>
       <li>like</li>
       <li>butter</li>
    </ul>
```

element inside the ul or ol element, it displaces to right. What do i do to stop the li element from getting displaced under the ul element, so that it lines up straight. Do anyone know how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move a ul list bullet marker very slightly to one direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810134/how-can-i-move-a-ul-list-bullet-marker-very-slightly-to-one-direction)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple fix with CSS. Apply a `padding: 0;` to the `ul` parent element

If you want to remove the bullets as well you can do that with the following styling `list-style-type: none;`

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>smooth</li>
   <li>like</li>
   <li>butter</li>
</ul>
```